# Calling platform specific SDK from Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I already have an Android and IOS SDK which can communicate to one of my clients and manipulate data. Is there a way I can call the methods in those SDK from Flutter.

For example: I have a method registerUser(String username) in my Android SDK. Currently I have to use the Flutter channel in a custom Android code and call the method registerUser(String username) from there. This adds overhead as I have to rewrite all my hundreds of methods in the custom code in Flutter or generate a new Android SDK that supports the Flutter calls.

So is there a way I can call the methods in my Android SDK from Flutter directly or using some interface which requires less efforts?

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
import "dart:io" show Platform;
...
if(Platform.isIOS){ ... }
if(Platform.isAndroid){ ... }
```